# Questions about limit points

Tags: general-topology

Let  $X=\{a,b\}$ with the indiscrete topology $T=\{X,\emptyset\}$.  Consider the subset $A=\{a\}$. What is the limit point of $A$? I understand that limit point $x$ of $A$ means every neighborhood of $x$ intersects $A$ in some point other than $x$ itself. However, for a set $A=\{a\}$, how could I find the limit point of $A$? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Well, you could start by listing the open sets in the topology, then looking at the ones that intersect $A$ ... there are not many open sets you need to look at.

Comment: I think you got your definition of limit point wrong. A point $x \in X$ is a limit point of $A \subseteq X$ when all neighbourhoods of $x$ (not $A$) have non-empty intersection with $A \setminus \{x\}$.

Comment: I think that's just a typo

Comment: So the open sets in the topology is {a,b}?

Comment: Since the space has only two elements, you could just try all of them.

Comment: Thank you, but a set U is called an open set if it does not contain any of its boundary points. What are the boundary points in T={X,∅} for X={a,b} ?

Comment: No. The open sets are those in $T$. That's the *definition* of a topology.

Answer (score 1):

An open set of the topology $T$ is simply an element of $T$. For a point $x$ to be a limit point of $A$, every neighborhood of $x$ must intersect $A$ in a point other than itself. Since your space is finite we can check each point individually.

- The point $a$ is not a limit point of $A$ because all its neighborhoods only intersect $A$ at $a$.
- The point $b$ is a limit point of $A$ because it has only *one* neighborhood, and that is the whole space $X$ which intersects $A$ on a point different than $b$ (namely $a$).

There are no more points so $b$ is the only limit point of $A$.